# Cloud Image - Delayed Boot after kernel 5.3 upgrade for 18.04

Tags: boot, kernel

So just testing things out and expecting failure, but ran through updating the kernel of my image to 5.3 from https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/. It starts up and all works well, but after a few restarts I noticed a long reboot time.

```
graphical.target @19min 44.970s
└─multi-user.target @19min 44.959s
  └─cloudflared.service @19min 40.657s +4.298s
    └─basic.target @19min 40.617s
      └─sockets.target @19min 40.614s
        └─snapd.socket @19min 40.589s +17ms
          └─sysinit.target @19min 40.548s
            └─cloud-init.service @19min 39.553s +982ms
              └─systemd-networkd-wait-online.service @19min 38.465s +1.084s
                └─systemd-networkd.service @19min 38.398s +53ms
                  └─network-pre.target @19min 38.394s
                    └─cloud-init-local.service @1.769s +19min 36.621s
                      └─systemd-remount-fs.service @678ms +95ms
                        └─systemd-journald.socket @675ms
                          └─system.slice @625ms
                            └─-.slice @611ms
```

Is it cloud init or some network delays given the `systemd-networkd-wait-online.service`, or something else?